# Show that $\phi(N) \leq H$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $\phi: G \to H$ be a group homomorphism and $N \leq G$ (with $G$, $N$ and $H$ groups).

Show that $\phi(N) \leq H$

---

So this is what I did:

Obviously $\phi(N)$ is a subset of H because $N$ is a subset of the domain $G$. Since $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ the identities of $G$ and $N$ are the same, namely: $e_G=e_N$. From this and the properties of homomorphisms it follows that $\phi(e_N)=\phi(e_N e_N)=\phi(e_N)\phi(e_N)=\phi(e_N)=e_H$.

So $e_H$ is an element of $\phi(N)$.

Suppose now $\phi(N)$ has elements $x$ and $y$ so that $x=\phi(a)$ and $y=\phi(b)$. By definition $a,b \in N$ and since $N$ is a group $ab^{-1} \in N$ as well.

> Lemma: $\phi(e_G)=\phi(bb^{-1})=\phi(b)\phi(b^{-1})=e_H$. If we multiply the last equation by $\phi(b)^{-1}$ we get $\phi(b)^{-1}\phi(b)\phi(b^{-1})=\phi(b)^{-1} e_H.$ Thus $\phi(b^{-1})=\phi(b)^{-1}$.

From the above and the properties of homomorphisms it follows that: $\phi(ab^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(b^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(b)^{-1}=xy^{-1}$. So for every $x,y \in \phi(N)$ we have $xy^{-1} \in \phi(N)$ as well. So $\phi(N)$ is closed under multiplication and inverses.

Now we have: $\phi(N)$ is a subset of $H$, is closed under multiplication and inverses and has the identity. Therefore $\phi(N)$ is a subgroup of $H$.

I'm pretty sure this is correct, but I wanted to make sure I didn't overlook something. Could somebody confirm I didn't make a mistake in my reasoning? I would appreciate it!

Comment: Looks good. Some of the language can be streamlined a little, but otherwise you have all the necessary details.

Comment: @walkar, thanks for checking! This course isn't in English so I just translated my proof the best I could.

Comment: I also tend to be a little terse in my writing. If I was showing all the details, I'd probably use bullet points for the three criteria and be as short as possible describing them, not justifying "this works because $N$ is a subgroup," etc. But that's just my style.